# No me halla el maximo y el minimo

Tags: python-3.x

Mi programa no funciona.

## Ejercicio 5.2 Escribe otro programa que pida una lista de números como la anterior y al final muestre por pantalla el máximo y mínimo de los números, en vez de la media.

```
try:
    #defino programas
    def mostrarmenor(m):
        print('\nEl numero menor es: ',m)

    def mostrarmayor(M):
        print('\nEl numero mayor es: ',M)

    def pedirdato():
        menor=None
        mayor=None
        while True:
            n=input('Ingrese un numero: ')
            if n=='fin':
                break
            if mayor is None or n>mayor:
                mayor=n
            if menor is None or n<menor:
                menor=n
        mostrarmayor(mayor)
        mostrarmenor(menor)
#Comienza Programa
    pedirdato()
#Fin del programa
except:
    print('\nError!! Ingrese un numero o la palabra "fin".\nEl programa ha finalizado')
```

**ENTRADA**

[image: Estas son las entradas]

**SALIDA**

[image: Esta es la salida]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. ¿Podrías aclarar exactamente qué es lo que no funciona de tu programa? Saludos

Comment: te falta castear el input a int, ya que estas comparando strings `numero = int(numero)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Por qué no hace lo que esperas

El problema es que en python3 la función `input()` devuelve una cadena. Esto afecta a cómo se compara con otras cadenas.

Ya que `mayor` y `menor` empiezan siendo `None`, ambas almacenarán la primera entrada introducida por el usuario, en la primera iteración del bucle. Por tanto ambas valdrán `"1"` tras la primera iteración, según el ejemplo que has puesto.

En la siguiente iteración, la entrada del usuario es `"10"`, que se compara con `"1"`. Ya que la comparación es entre cadenas, se comparan *alfabéticamente* y no *numéricamente*. Es decir, al comparar `"1"` con `"10"`, es como si comparases `"a"` con `"al"`. No tiene en cuenta que `"10"` representa una cantidad, sino que es simplemente una secuencia de dígitos. Al comenzar por el mismo carácter, pero ser más larga que `"1"`, considera que es mayor (va después alfabéticamente), por lo que la variable `mayor` tomará el valor `"10"`.

En la siguiente iteración el usuario introduce `"4"` y aquí es donde vienen las sorpresas. Al comparar `"4"` con `"10"`, resulta que `"4"` es mayor porque va después alfabéticamente (el primer carácter de la cadena `"4"` es posterior alfabéticamente al primer carácter de la cadena `"10"`). Es como comparar `"e"` con `"al"` . Y de ahí el resultado que obtienes.

## Cómo resolverlo

Convierte a `int` la entrada del usuario, una vez has visto que no es `"fin"`. Es decir:

```
def pedirdato():
    menor=None
    mayor=None
    while True:
        n=input('Ingrese un numero: ')
        if n=='fin':
            break
        n = int(n)    # <----- AQUI
        if mayor is None or n>mayor:
            mayor=n
        if menor is None or n<menor:
            menor=n
```

### Otras observaciones

No es habitual definir funciones dentro de un `try`. Ya que tu `try` básicamente está para verificar que ha introducido un dato correcto, debería estar "protegiendo" la zona que lee el dato y trata de convertirlo a entero, y no todo el código. Yo lo pondría así:

```py
def mostrarmenor(m):
    print('\nEl numero menor es: ',m)

def mostrarmayor(M):
    print('\nEl numero mayor es: ',M)

def pedirdato():
    menor=None
    mayor=None
    while True:
        n=input('Ingrese un numero: ')
        if n=='fin':
            break
        try:
            n = int(n)
        except:
            print('\nError!! Ingrese un numero o la palabra "fin".\nEl programa ha finalizado')
            quit()

        if mayor is None or n>mayor:
            mayor=n
        if menor is None or n<menor:
            menor=n
    mostrarmayor(mayor)
    mostrarmenor(menor)

pedirdato()
```

Comment: Excelente explicacion!!. Muchisima Gracias!. Ahora mismo lo arreglo!